# Ansible: AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible_eth1'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, virtual-machine

I'm trying to provision an AWS EC2 instance with Ansible but in a certain task it returns:

> "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible_eth1' is undefined"

My question is: what hell is 'ansible_eth1' ,I means: where I found this dammit variable? I googled "where I found ansible_eth1 variable" and things like that but no luck·

My collectd.conf.j2 is:

```
# For each instance where collectd is running, we define 
# hostname proper to that instance. When metrics from
# multiple instances are aggregated, hostname will tell 
# us were they came from.

Hostname "dash"

# Fully qualified domain name, false for our little lab
FQDNLookup false

# Plugins we are going to use with their configurations,
# if needed
LoadPlugin cpu

LoadPlugin df
<Plugin df>
        Device "/dev/sda1"
        MountPoint "/"
        FSType "ext4"
        ReportReserved true
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin interface
<Plugin interface>
        Interface "eth0"
        Interface "eth1"
        IgnoreSelected false
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin network
<Plugin network>
  <Server "{{ ansible_eth1.ipv4.address }}" "25826">
  </Server>
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin memory

LoadPlugin syslog
<Plugin syslog>
        LogLevel info
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin swap

<Include "/etc/collectd/collectd.conf.d">
        Filter "*.conf"
</Include>
```

I think is that, I hope the point has been made clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, add playbook snippet with task in question and full error message to get some real help.

Comment: Ok, I will post the playbook and the error message as a answer

Comment: You should edit OP with additional info instead of posting it as answer. The problem is inside your `collectd.conf.j2` template.

Comment: Done,I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Your collectd.cong.j2 is using the undefined variable ansible_eth1.ipv4.address.
You can check it using debug:

```
- name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
  debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

You have to define that variable in inventory or in any other place ansible accepts. Look at [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html).

And also, I don't think you should use ansible_ prefix for that variable in your case.